# How to display text over image in toolText for fusion charts React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fusioncharts

I am doing react native project and in that we are using fusion charts for showing different graphs. But, In those graphs while user tap on the plots(graph lines) we are showing tooltips.

But, We have to show tooltip like below screenshot.

Note: Text will be dynamic

[image]

In tooltip attributes, We found only bgColor, bordercolor etc only, We did not found any bgImage or setting two colos for bg.
So, We tried like setting image in tooltext, but, still getting issue.

> We can't setting Text over the image, It's coming in bottom of image.

```
 {
          "label": "Mickey",
          "value": "92",
          "toolText": "<div class='container'><img height='50' width='50' position:relative text-align: center color: white alt='' src='http://www.pngpix.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/PNGPIX-COM-Mickey-Mouse-PNG-Transparent-Image-1-500x575.png'></img><div class='top-left'>Top Left</div></div>"
}
```

Output is following.

[image]

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts tooltip does not support setting multiple background color in the tooltip.

Also tooltip cannot be set a background image, alternatively as a work-around you can set a  in "toolText" attribute. And set your image using  in the div as below :

"toolText": "http://www.pngpix.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/PNGPIX-COM-Mickey-Mouse-PNG-Transparent-Image-1-500x575.png' style=' opacity: 0.5;'>

To set text as well as image, that need to be implemented using the  tag as below in the "toolText" attribute :

"toolText": "http://www.pngpix.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/PNGPIX-COM-Mickey-Mouse-PNG-Transparent-Image-1-500x575.png' style=' opacity: 0.5;'>Centered"

Comment: Where is the text you have added here?

Comment: Without <div>, the above toolText showing as just text, Nothing apart from it showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way hope it will help you out, please refer the demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9uy7fhbq/)

```
    const dataSource = {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Greenhouse gas emissions produced by foods ",
        "subCaption": "During Production",
        "yAxisName":"Kg Co₂E",
         "showValues":"0",
        "yAxisMaxValue":"25",
        "yAxisMinValue":"0",
         "showToolTip":"1",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "data": [{
          "label": "Lamb",
          "value": "22"
        },
        {
          "label": "Beef",
          "value": "16"
        },
        {
          "label": "Farmed Salmon",
          "value": "4"
        },
        {
          "label": "White Rice",
          "value": "3.9"
        },
        {
          "label": "Brown Rice",
          "value": "3.54"
        },
        {
          "label": "Eggs",
          "value": "2.5"
        }
      ]
    };

FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var myChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: "spline",
    renderAt: "chart-container",
    width: "100%",
    height: "400",
    dataFormat: "json",
    dataSource
  }).render();
   function handler(eventObj, dataObj) {

     var id =eventObj.data.dataIndex;
     if(id===0)
       {
         myChart.setChartAttribute("plottooltext", "<div id='nameDiv' style='font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom: 3px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;border-style: none; background-color: #ffffff;' ><img style='height:40px; width:50px;background-color: #ffffff;' src='https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-yiqNTXFRiAI/UICj02XTQ0I/AAAAAAAAAIg/xVPoKagJEm0/s1600/CABRA.jpg'</div>{br}Co<sub>2</sub>E: <b>$dataValue</b>");
       }
     else if(id===1){
       myChart.setChartAttribute("plottooltext", "<div id='nameDiv' style='font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom: 3px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;border-style: none;background-color: #ffffff;' ><img style='height:50px; width:60px;background-color: #ffffff;' src='https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180221/vuq/kisspng-sheep-cattle-horse-livestock-farm-vector-animal-cow-5a8d75a1e781b6.1693995215192201299483.jpg'</div>{br}Co<sub>2</sub>E: <b>$dataValue</b>");
     }
       else if(id===2){
       myChart.setChartAttribute("plottooltext", "<div id='nameDiv' style='font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom: 3px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;border-style: none;background-color: #ffffff;' ><img style='height:40px; width:50px;background-color: #ffffff;' src='https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180707/lqx/kisspng-sardine-coho-salmon-trout-atlantic-salmon-salmon-5b418018d671c4.2868322115310192888784.jpg'</div>{br}Co<sub>2</sub>E: <b>$dataValue</b>");
     }
       else if(id===3){
       myChart.setChartAttribute("plottooltext", "<div id='nameDiv' style='font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom: 3px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;border-style: none;background-color: #ffffff;' ><img style='height:40px; width:50px;background-color: #ffffff;' src='https://cdn-a.william-reed.com/var/wrbm_gb_food_pharma/storage/images/5/1/8/1/1411815-1-eng-GB/Genetically-engineered-rice-proves-to-produce-high-yields-of-rotavirus-specific-antibody.jpg'</div>{br}Co2E: <b>$dataValue</b>");
     }
       else if(id===4){
       myChart.setChartAttribute("plottooltext", "<div id='nameDiv' style='font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom: 3px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;border-style: none;' ><img style='height:40px; width:50px;' src='https://imageresizer.pollotropical.fuzzhq.com/resize/?source=https://koala-marketing-api-production.s3.amazonaws.com/pollo-tropical/assets/BrownRice.png&height=9999&width=600&max_quality=85'</div>{br}Co<sub>2</sub>E: <b>$dataValue</b>");
     }
       else if(id===5){
       myChart.setChartAttribute("plottooltext", "<div id='nameDiv' style='font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom: 3px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;border-style: none;' ><img style='height:40px; width:50px;' src='https://us.123rf.com/450wm/andegro4ka/andegro4ka1504/andegro4ka150400029/39383340-stock-vector-broken-egg-shells-isolated-on-white-photo-realistic-vector-illustration.jpg?ver=6'</div>{br}Co<sub>2</sub>E: <b>$dataValue</b>");
     }
    }
  myChart.addEventListener("dataplotRollOver", handler);
```

});

Refre the docs - https://www.fusioncharts.com/features/tooltips